# Writing a function to insert the rows in a table from some other table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a requirement to write a Postgres function to insert rows into one table from the other tables. But the problem is that only few columns needs to be set from the rows of the other table rest I need to set by myself.

In below table i just to fetch the `youth_enrollment_id, youth_email` from some other table rest column I will set as hard coded. I am trying something like below but it is not working

```
INSERT INTO moyadev.notification_email_details(
        id, youth_enrollment_id, youth_email, email_subject, email_body, 
        status, attempt, sent_date, last_updated_by, last_updated)
uuid_generate_v4(), 
SELECT id, email 
from moyadev.youth_enrollment, 
'subject', 'body', 'PENDING', '', '', 'SYSTEM', '2016-12-24 17:02:18.181'
```

and gives below error.

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "uuid_generate_v4"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 205
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic `INSERT` and `SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO moyadev.notification_email_details
       (id, youth_enrollment_id, youth_email, ..., last_updated)
SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), 
       ye.id, ye.email,
       'subject', 'body', 'PENDING', '', '', 
       'SYSTEM', '2016-12-24 17:02:18.181'
FROM moyadev.youth_enrollment AS ye ;
```